# Firefox uses URL-encoded part of href as the whole href

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, href, anchor

I have a html tag with a query parameter containing a URL-encoded URI:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <a href="https://google.com/maps?endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fbing.com%2Fmaps">Click me</a>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, the anchor tag shows up correctly, as https://google.com/maps?endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fbing.com%2Fmaps.

However, viewing the anchor tag in Firefox shows https://bing.com/maps. It has discarded the first part of the URL, and used the encoded query param as the href. I would expect it to show the same as in Chrome. Why does this happen? Is this a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Firefox 100.0.2 (64-bit) Mac.

Comment: same here on Firefox 101.0 (64 bit) Win10. It just works as expected. Are you sure such a problem was caused by firefox itself? maybe you have some addons changing the dom?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 101, Chrome 102

Comment: Can't reproduce with Win10 and Firefox 101.0 (64-bit) with local test.html file

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it was an addon. This was the culprit: https://github.com/hyperfekt/webextension-remove-redirect